# Spring Boot: How to run an update query from inside a @scheduled cron method?

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-data-jpa

I have a table named "docket_seq" with only 1 column "next_val". I need to reset the value of next_val everyday at a certain time. I have written the update query is as follows:

```
package com.xxx.xxx.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.xxx.xxx.model.DocketSequence;

@Repository
public interface DocketSequenceRepository extends JpaRepository<DocketSequence, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE DocketSequence SET next_val='1'")
    Long resetDateSequence(@Param("next_val") Long next_val);       
}
```

I am running the cron job as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.xxx.xxx.model.DocketSequence;
import com.xxx.xxx.repository.DocketSequenceRepository;

@Component
public class ResetDocketSequence {
    @Autowired
    DocketSequenceRepository docketSequenceRepository;

    DocketSequence docketSequence; 

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 06 23 * * ?", zone = "Asia/Calcutta")
    public void resetSequence() {   
        docketSequenceRepository.save(docketSequence);
        System.out.println("Cron job has run");      
     }
}
```

When I execute the code and the cron job runs, I get the error: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Target object must not be null. I have tried a lot of things but I think that there would be a simple way to just update the value of a column on a table.

Comment: try @Query("UPDATE docket_seqSET next_val=:next_val")

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a constrain like `NOT NULL` for the column in your db. Hence, you can't save null values.

The `DocketSequence docketSequence;` is null when the cron job starts, because there is no initialization.

Define a default value for your `DocketSequence` to update the  value in your database.
Another option would be to allow null values for your column.